# FFMPEG: FFPLAY binary not getting generated on compilation

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have downloaded FFMPEG with FFPLAY enabled code from: https://github.com/cus/ffplay

I use the following command to configure and make the package:

```
./configure --enable-ffplay
make
```

Here it shows that:
`SDL support               no`
as one of the outputs. But i have sdl packages installed in my system.

However, the packages created are:

```
ffmpeg
ffmpeg_g
ffserver
ffserver_g
ffprobe
ffprobe_g
```

I have referred this post : http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Compiling-FFMPEG-with-ffplay-support-td3414041.html But this didn't help out.

I checked my config.log, it has the below lines:

```
ffplay='yes'
ffplay_deps='avcodec avformat swscale swresample sdl'
ffplay_select='rdft crop_filter'
```

I have the sdl packages installed in my system. What is the issue actually. Could anyone please guide me through this.

Comment: on ubuntu I use `git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
` and it works great. Have you installed the development version of SDL?

Comment: @FredrikPihl: I suppose i have as previously when i had compiled in same system, ffplay binary was getting created. However please do provide a link in ubuntu for development version of SDL in form of answer. If it works i'll accept the answer.

Comment: @Zax : Have you got ffplay binary file?

Answer (score 19):

In ubuntu 13.04, this is howto install [libsdl-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libsdl1.2-dev):

sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev

sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev     #  16.04 and up https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

One way to check if the dev-package is installed is to see if the following binary is installed:

```
$ which sdl-config 
/usr/bin/sdl-config
```

And, consider to use the official git-repo:

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
```

Comment: And on Fedora the package is named SDL-devel

Comment: It worked for me thanks. For latest pkg execute below command
    sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev

Comment: yep, on ubuntu 17.04 use libsdl2-dev NOT libsdl-dev (libsdl1.2-dev)

Comment: @neok -- True. [The Times They Are A Changin'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7qQ6_RV4VQ).

Comment: On CentOS 7 with ffmpeg 4.1.3, I needed to do `sudo yum install SDL2-devel`

Answer (score 11):

I ran in the same problem, as pointed by other answers in general it's due to the lack of some dependency. You can check your ffplay dependencies by running:

`grep ffplay_deps ffbuild/config.log`

In my case (Linux Mint 18) I get the following:

> ffplay_deps='avcodec avformat swscale swresample sdl2'

So you have to install all the listed libraries/dependencies. In my particular case I had to install libsdl2-dev in order to fix the problem. If everything is Ok ffplay must appear in the configured programs. You can check this easily by running:

```
./configure --enable-ffplay | grep "Programs:" -A4
```

So you get something like:

> Programs:
> ffmpeg            ffplay          ffprobe

Comment: A little note: the `-A1` switch displays **one** line. In my case ffmpeg (3.4.9) displayed 4 programs, with `ffplay` on a second line. So it didn't show. Took me a couple of hours to discover. So be safe and  make it `-A2` or more.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for reporting the issue

Answer (score 1):

I was spent 2 weeks to install newest version ffmpeg 2.8.11. This version is used for Ubuntu 16.04. I advise you should install this version. I tested on Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked well. You can install libav-tools like directions above but you will have a problem about compatibility. Because libav-tools and ffmpeg now was developed by two different group.
Following my directions. If you have any problem can sent me via an email: hohaidang.khtn@gmail.com

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential checkinstall git libfaac-dev libgpac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev librtmp-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev pkg-config texi2html yasm zlib1g-dev  libavcodec-extra-53
$ sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config texinfo zlib1g-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libgsm1 libgsm1-dev libopenjpeg-dev libschroedinger-1.0-0 libschroedinger-dev libschroedinger-doc libspeex-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
$ wget https://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.8.11.tar.xz
$ tar xf ffmpeg-2.8.11.tar.xz
$ cd ffmpeg-2.8.11/
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --disable-yasm // disable yasm if you are using Ubuntu 12.04, if not --enable-yasm
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Check ffmpeg, ffserver, ffplay, ffprobe in terminal.
Good luck

Comment: FFmpeg 2.8 release branch is old. Why would you use that?

Comment: I think this 2.8 release is not old. This was release on 2017-02-09. And this version is stable for Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using this and it works well for me.

Comment: 2.8 was derived from the master branch on 2015-09-05. Releases do not get any additional features or other major updates: only the occasional security or bugfix backport. So you're missing 19 months of updates which is a whole different epoch in FFmpeg time. If it works for you that's fine, but in no way is it not old.

Comment: Thanks for you advice.

Comment: Hello  LordNeckbeard, I tested what you told me. I tried compile ffmpeg-3.2.4 and after commanded 'make install'. I did not see 'ffplay'. Maybe this version is not as fit as Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: that commandline is screwed up!  it has repeated --enable flags